# How can I attach a fourth external monitor to my MacBook Pro 15" from mid-2015?

Tags: mac, multiple-monitors, macbook-pro

I am running MacOS Mojave (10.14.3):

- MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2015)
- Processor: 2.8 GHz Intel Core i7
- Memory: 16 GB 1600 MHz DDR3
- Graphics: AMD Radeon R9 M370X 2048 MB Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB

I have attached three external monitors:

- Acer: UHD 4K2K (model B286HK)
- Asus: ProArt (1900 x 1200)
- GeChic 1503H

I have one monitor plugged into each of the two mini-display port ports and one monitor plugged into the HDMI port. I want a fourth external monitor, but I am out of ports.

Is there a way to attach a fourth external monitor?

Answer (score 2):

Here are some options:

- If at least two of your displays have dual Thunderbolt ports,
  you only need one Thunderbolt port for these displays using
  [Thunderbolt Daisy Chaining](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/thunderbolt-daisychain-connect-mac-accessories/).
- You can use a dock that will convert a USB port to a new Thunderbolt or
  HDMI port.
- Similarly, an adapter for USB 2.0/3.x to VGA/DVI/HDMI could create a new display
  adapter, but a driver might be required (read
  [this article](https://dannysullivan.com/macbook-pro-multimonitor-4-monitors-at-once-1577)).

Comment: Umm, according to Apple: https://support.apple.com/kb/SP719?locale=en_US. Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native resolution on the built-in display and up to 3840 by 2160 pixels on up to two external displays, [...] There is also an HDMI port that you can presumably add a 3rd monitor. I am doubtful that this Mac supports 4 *external* displays. Possibly 3 external plus the internal though.

Comment: @SteveChambers is likely on the right track here. A user on Ask Different claims to have done it (https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/191732/23959), but considers the laptop's screen as one of the monitors. In addition, the situation seems very specific.